# Get-ChildItem can't find one specific directory?

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am writing a PowerShell script which is supposed to take a look at a directory, sort the children by name (numbered names) and check if there's a specific file inside. If there is, it's supposed to be copied somewhere, if not it's supposed to look at the next one. This is my code so far:

```
#[...]
$notExist = $true
#$LatestCiClient = [some directory from earlier in the script]
$buildDirectories = Get-ChildItem -Path $LatestCiClient | Sort Name -Descending

while ($notExist) {
    $currentDir = $buildDirectories | Select-Object -First 1
    $assembliesDir = Get-ChildItem -Path $currentDir.FullName -Include Desktop-Assemblies #Breakpoint
    $script:exe = Get-ChildItem -Path $assembliesDir -Include SomeFile.exe | Select -First 1
    if ($Script:exe.Exists) {
        $notExist = $false
    } else {
        if ($buildDirectories.Count -gt 0) {
            $buildDirectories = $buildDirectories | Select -Skip 1
        } else {
            $script:NoneFound = $true
            $script:notExist = $false
        }
    }
}
#[more Powershell that is supposed to copy $script:exe]
```

I am getting the numbered directories (`$buildDirectories`), in the debugger I see the whole list.

I enter the `while block (breakpoint is set at "#Breakpoint"), select the first directory to check (`$currentDir`, which is again there and correct) and look for a folder called "Desktop-Assemblies".

I am looking at it, in the Explorer, right now, the folder is there, it's filled, it's not hidden (it is read-only but that shouldn't matter?), I am not doing anything I haven't done several times in the script - nothing. `$assembliesDir` is empty.

I tried using "Desktop-Assemblies", I tried Desktop*,  I tried without the `-Include` . If I use `$currentDir` it says

> Cannot find path [WeirdPath] because it doesn't exist

Weird Path being the FolderName of my `$currentDir` but the rest of the path is C:\Users\MyUserName.

If I use `$currentDir.FullName` it finds all the directories, INCLUDING the one I am looking for. I should probably add that the whole directory that is being searched is on another computer, it's a network drive.

Comment: To make sure we have the basics right, let me ask if the value of `$LatestCiClient` is something like `\\othercomputername\path\to\target\directory`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it is. "\\PCNAME\superdrops" to be exact

Comment: Can you try this? `Get-ChildItem -Path $LatestCiClient -Recurse -Directory | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Desktop-Assemblies'}` assuming the name of the directory is exactly as i put in the code.

Comment: It finds multiple results (from several of the numbered directories).

Comment: I just tried `$assembliesDir = Get-ChildItem -Path $currentDir -Include 'Desktop-Assemblies'` and `$assembliesDir = Get-ChildItem -Path $currentDir.FullName -Include 'Desktop-Assemblies'` - Again no result.

Comment: What about these 2 variations. `$assembliesDir = Get-ChildItem -Path $currentDir.FullName -Recurse` and 
`$assembliesDir = Get-ChildItem -Path $currentDir.FullName`

Comment: Since you are just interested in the path itself, why don't you use [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-6) (and [`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-6))?

Comment: I ended up using the `|Where-Object{...}` - Syntax instead of the `-Include` Syntax in the lines that weren't working. Seems successful so far, thanks a lot for the help.  @RohinSidharth If you post an answer to this post I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use this?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $currentDir.FullName | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Desktop-Assemblies'}
```

Comment: Yep! Guess -Include isn't mean for finding a single file.